# How do we know $ n $ is a multiple of $ 2 $ from the equation $ 2 =\frac{ n^2} { d^2} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

My attempt at answering starts by observing that if a number $ n $ is a multiple of $ 2 $, then it can be written in the form $ n = i \cdot 2 $ where $ i $ is some integer.  Now I assume that there is some step to get from $ 2 = \frac{n^2}{d^2} $ to the form $ n =i \cdot 2 $ but I can't figure out how to do so, or if I am on the right track.  I am sorry to ask such a shallow question, but it's been so long since high-school math and my brain just fails to fire the electrical signals in a way to solve basic mathematical problems, even if my adult (conceptual/intuitive) understanding of a situation might be there.

The corollary of this would be that "since $ n $ is a multiple of $ 2 $ then $ n^2 $ is a multiple of $ 4 $, which seems obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows by *parity:* $\ 2d^2 = n^2 $ is even, so $\,n\,$ is even, since $ $ odd$^2\!$ = odd $\cdot$ odd = odd.

Answer (score 4):

The usual argument says that $n^2=2d^2$; so if $2\mid n^2$, then since $2$ is a prime, $2\mid n$ or $2\mid n$.

Comment: Such a simple answer!

Comment: And $ 2 | n^2 $ because we see that $ 2 $ is a multiple on the right hand side of the equation?

Comment: @mindandsky: yes; since $d^2\in\mathbb{Z}$, $2\mid n^2$.

Comment: How do we go from $ 2 | n^2 $ from $ 2 | n $?  I do not understand the explanation that "since 2 is prime, then $ 2 | n $ ?  Can you show it and explain to me like I'm five?  Thank you!

Comment: @mindandsky If $p$ is a prime and $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. See [Euclid's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).